# CSS layout not working as I hoped

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to line up two rows with data inside a Bootstrap WELL. But, cant get it to line up? Im not the best CSS guy out there, could someone give me a hand?

Here is the code (required Bootstrap, and chartjs for the chart component):

```
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;" id="listSetions">
    <!-- FIRST INFO ROW -->
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 well" style="background: #fff;">

            <h1>Belize</h1>

            <div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
                    Total Units
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">63%</h1>
                    Occupancy Rate
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">235</h1>
                    <span style="width: 8px; height: 8px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #51BBF5;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Occupied
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1000</h1>
                    <span style="width: 8px; height: 8px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #FFD1F0;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Unoccupied
                </div>

                <div style="text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; float: left;" ><canvas id="sectionOverview1" width="130" height="130"></canvas></div>

            </div>

            <div>

               <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
                    Total Units
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">63%</h1>
                    Occupancy Rate
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">235</h1>
                    <span style="width: 8px; height: 8px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #51BBF5;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Occupied
                </div>
                <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
                    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1000</h1>
                    <span style="width: 8px; height: 8px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #FFD1F0;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Unoccupied
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    var section1_data = [{ value: 200, color: "#51BBF5" }, { value: 35, color: "#FFD1F0"}];
    var section1 = document.getElementById("sectionOverview1").getContext("2d");
    var chart_section1 = new Chart(section1).Doughnut(section1_data);


    </script>
```

Im sure the intended layout is obvious. Hope you guys can help out!

**NOTE:** here is the [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf3HY/).

Regards,

Bob

Comment: It would be better if you have used jsFiddle for your snippet.

Comment: Have never use that. Ill look.

Comment: Couldnt make it work.

Comment: Like this? http://jsbin.com/jiwol/2/edit

Comment: Yes! Just like that! Let me copy your code and try locally, david

Comment: I just added `class="clearfix"` to the container divs.  It's a Bootstrap classname for clearing (uses micro clearfix).

Comment: Works like a charm! Post as answer and ill mark it the answer. Thanks ALOT!

Comment: Posted answer.  I also think it could benefit from some more Bootstrappifying (good word?).  I'll update my answer with suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `class="clearfix"` to the container divs.  It's a Bootstrap helper class that uses the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="well" style="width:150px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px; background: #fff;">
    <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
    Total Units
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/jiwol/2/edit)

---

Note that you could make use of some of Bootstrap's grid functionality by doing something like this:

http://jsbin.com/jiwol/3/edit

Plus of course the standard note that you shouldn't style inline...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;" id="listSetions"> 
  <!-- FIRST INFO ROW -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 well" style="background: #fff;">
      <h1>Belize</h1>
      <div class="col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div  class="col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background: #fff;">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;">1235</h1>
            Total Units </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7akSM/)